# Getting 0.0 for longitude and latitude on tablet

Tags: android, location-provider

I am getting `longitude=0.0` and `latitude=0.0` on tablet while this is working perfectly on the phone.

I am using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` and not the `GPS_PROVIDER` so what could be the cause please?
Logcat output??

that's my code:

```
 // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
         locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     // Define a listener that responds to location updates
     locationListener = new LocationListener() {
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
           longitude=location.getLongitude();
           latitude=location.getLatitude();

         }


         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
       };

     //Or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
     String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

     // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);

     Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

     if(lastKnownLocation!=null){
         longitude=lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
         latitude=lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();

     }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with more info, is your tablet CDMA or GSM enabled?

Comment: If the same code works on a phone in the same location, I'd guess that perhaps the tablet doesn't have a mobile data connection, so can't triangulate from cell towers? But we'd be better off seeing your code and knowing the specs of the tablet. And whether it has WiFi turned on, etc.

Comment: yes my wifi is on but don't know where to check for CDMA and GSM actually will check google for that..

Comment: Does your tablet support SIM?

Comment: Sorry but actually the tablet is not mine so I don't know lots of things about it.. trying to know more about it but thought that it should work I have my wifi on and the  Location service settings checked as to let the app to use wifi to determine my approximate location...

Comment: It's ployer Momo 12 and it doesn't support a SIM card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Location settings inside your device settings. This seems not a problem with your code, but your device settings. In my **Ginger bread**, it's as:

**Settings -> Location&security -> Use wireless networks**

Comment: I have Location services> Location and google search it's checked; and Google's location service that permits the apps to use wifi to detect my location.. on

Comment: Did you check the program with any other device? Atleast you can confirm that the error is with coding or not

Comment: It worked thanks; it seems that it needed more time to detect the modifications..

Comment: Thanks... tablets Ijoy are.... pff I don't have words, But when I try move camer in x latitude and y longitude, tablet position random why ?